# Need help understanding what happens when we create a new BindingContext for data bound fields

Tags: c#, data-binding

**BACKGROUND:**  You have a form with two text boxes.  Each text box is bound to the same field in a typed dataset.

Using the visuals studio designer you bind each textboxes Text property.  This is what the generated code looks like in the InitializeComponent() method...

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.testDataSet1, "TestTable.TestID", true));
```

Very basic so far.   Now you add a button whose click event adds a row to the typed dataset.   When you do this the two data bound text boxes show the first row.  Here is what the simple click event looks like.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.testDataSet1.TestTable.AddTestTableRow(nTestID++, "Test" + nTestID.ToString());
    }
```

Ok great, so know we want to move the databound fields between the dataset rows .  To do this we simply create a BindingManagerBase object and grab ahold of the BindingManagerBase object that exists in the Forms BindingContext property.

```
private BindingManagerBase currentMgr = null;
```

In the forms constructor you do the following

```
this.currentMgr = this.bc[this.testDataSet1, "TestTable"];
```

Then elsewhere in the code we can use the currentMgr to move to the next record.

```
this.currentMgr.Position++;
```

Yes this is all basic!

**ISSUE:** Now for the part I don't understand and could use help with...

Lets say you want the ability to have the one of the text boxes display a different row from the DataSet.   Ah, this should be easy.

Create a new BindingContext and then assign the first text boxes BindingContext property to this new BindingContext.  Then get the BindingManagerBase object that exists in this new BindingContext and use that to navigate the rows.

The problem is when you create a new BindingContext and assign that to the text boxes BindingContext property and then load data into the DataSet the text box displays the text *System.Data.DataRowView*.

Here is what the code looks like, very simple..

```
    private BindingContext bc;
    private BindingManagerBase currentMgr = null;
    private BindingManagerBase currentMgr2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.bc = new BindingContext();
        this.textBox1.BindingContext = this.bc;

        this.currentMgr = this.BindingContext[this.testDataSet1, "TestTable"];
        this.currentMgr2 = this.bc[this.testDataSet1, "TestTable"];
    }
```

When I debug this code and look at *this.BindingContext[this.testDataSet1,"TestTable"]* (which is the form's bindingcontext) and *this.bc[this.testDataSet1,"TestTable"]* they both return a RelatedCurrencyManager object.

If both of these binding context's return similar (obviously not the same) RelatedCurrencyManager objects, why does the text box bound to the new BindingContext display the text *System.Data.DataRowView* and never display data from the dataset?

I have looked at each RelatedCurrencyManager object numerous times in the debugger to see if I can tell if one property is different from the other RelatedCurrencyManager object but everything appears the same :-(.

I know that the forms BindingContext is created and initialized at a different time then my new BindingContext and I assume that is what my problem is but I cannot pinpoint this issue.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Thanks,